# Using 8bit ports as 8bit I/O variable (while using USB,I2C, SPI and Serial) - keyboard

Tags: hardware

**I am seeking HW.**

I would like to make keyboard with enhanced functions (RGB backlite, macros, programmed profiles etc) driven by some small MCU (Arduino Micro Pro or something similar).

To support communication, it needs to use **I2C** and **SPI**(for display and other devices), use **USB** (to communicate with PC) and use **Serial** to communicate with other Arduinos/MCUs.

The main function would be scanning keyboard matrix (like from 8x8 to 16x8 in maximal variant). The matrix would use diodes for NKRO (not ghosting, any key combination possible).

It would be really nice to have HW, where I could use 3 full ports as input (or as output) with benefit of reading/writing them with only one assembly instruction for 8bit manipulation, not to cycle over array of pins and manipulate each one independently (digitalRead/digitalWrite, which use tons of instructions to determine ports and pin and then combine them together to obtain one 8bit variable). Something like:

```
byte dataout,datain1,datain2;
PORT_A=dataout;
datain1=PORT_B;
datain2=PORT_C;
```

**Does anyone know, if there is such nonexpensive MCU and which type it is?**

On typical Arduino each port is "poluted" by some importaint communications pins, so none of them can be used as full 8bit I/O.

**Second question: Is there a reason, why are the most used communication pins spread over range of different ports and not collected on one port, while leaving other ports as full 8bit GPIO useable?**

Thank for all answers.

Comment: Seems mostly a problem of how many pins you need for your keyboard. You didn't state, how many pins you need. You seem to need an MCU with native USB support.

Comment: Define "Non-Expensive"...

Comment: Personally I'm a fan of the PIC32. It has 16 bit IO ports not 8 bit (though not all pins are populated on all ports), so you could `LATE = dataout; datain = PORTB;` for example.

Comment: @chrisl Yes, I want to make USB keyboard for PC (and also use it for other purposes so need to suppor I2C, SPI and UART too) Except this, I want for the keyboard 8+8 pins (for matrix 64 keys) or better 8+16 pins (for full keyboard with aditional keys like macros, multimedia, layout switches etc.)

Comment: Personally I do not see the need to save some instructions. Mostly you want combined ports to achieve high performance, but a keyboard is operated by a human normally, which is VERY slow compared to an MCU scanning all keys. Or do you need microsecond latency?

Comment: You can use shift registers (both parallel-in-serial-out and serial-in-parallel-out) connected to the SPI bus. You can then transmit one or two bytes over SPI, which is extremely fast (8 MHz clock on even the most basic Arduinos). You can daisy chain two shift registers if you want 16 inputs.
As others have mentioned, you don't really have to worry about the speed of human input devices.

Comment: @Majenko nonexpensive - I am using some Arduinos from aliexpress, about 2-3EUR each and at worst I can add some shift register for few cents to expand pin count and be able to do the work. On Arduino shop the same are about 8-20$. Both works well. So something around this range (say 1-30$?, not 100+$)

Comment: tttapa+MichelKeijzers: I know that, but was also thinking about some "code elegance" as why do 8 loops of about 50 instructions each for what could be done by just two instructions as well (so in like 200x less). I know I can do it somehow anyway and do all others tasks also somehow  (like the USB and manipulation of 20+ WS2812B
LED and OLED display and rot. encoder and who knows what else I came with) to not be excesivelly slow, but it counts together fast and I would like for once do it effective, not just pile library over library and compensate unnecessery ineffectiveness with faster HW.

Comment: You could read and entire port, and apply a mask, so only the bits you're interested in remain. Slightly more code, but faster than 16 digitalReads. But I'm counting that you'd need 32 GPIO pins, plus USB, So I think that's the problem you should focus on.

Comment: @Majenko is there some PIC32, which you would recomend me for start? Having USB and beat AVR32U4 is enought for me to give it try :) (So probably some cheaper model would be more than enought)

Comment: @Gerben for my current try it is 2 (I2C display+communication PD0-1) + 4 SPI (PB0-3) + USB (D+ D-) + 2 Serial (PD2-3) + 16 GPIO (PB4-7,PD4-7, PC6-7,PF0-1,4-7 ) - from that 16 GPIO I would use 8 as inputs, 1 for LEDs, 3 as outputs for 3-to-8 decoder (as only 1 row is active at each time) and have 4 free, or I would use 7 as outputs for 8x7 matrix which works for normal keyboard (128 keys, no external chip).

Comment: @gilhad You could do worse than the Fubarino SD

Comment: @Majenko thank you :) Looks interesting :) I will try it :)

Comment: If you use a diode separated key matrix, I don't see a way to press two or three keys at once if you don't implement a anti ghosting algorithm in your controller. To work, the capturing of the pins must be very fast. Nearly at once. And the mcu must be fast enough to find even a really short delay for pressing two or three keys. If there is a delay we, assume a human pressed the keys. That's anti ghosting. An expensive way of avoiding ghost keys is reading all keys separate  into a chain of shift registers. Or build a DAC with a resitore chain and read the analog value. One Channel = 10 Bits

Comment: To answer your second question: The pin setup depends on the internal layout of the chip. It is easier the have functional groups in their own blocks, e.g. the clock logic and the shift registers. The manufacturer chooses the pin position the way, it needs the shortest wiring of the gold wires and also it should avoid crossing wires.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer Key matrix input is read in the way, tah you attach signal to one row, then read all collumns to see, if signal is there. If it is there, then the key on crossing of row and collumn is pressed. Then continou with other row and after you check all rows, you know, which keys are pressed. Ghosting happens, if there are no diodes and user press keys on 3 crossings, that forms rectangle. Then even for the unpressed crossing is there signal, as it travels over the rest 3 and "ghost key" is detected, as we see the signal there, even if the key is not pressed. No speed helps here.

Comment: If there ARE diodes, then pressing the 3 keys does not make way for the 4. as diodes disallow the signal freelly travel to other rows. Even slow mcu can read that safely (as long as it does that faster, then human free the keys - say in 0.1s = eternity for mcu. Faster mcu can get more precise time of pressing, nothin more). No special algorithmus is needed here too. Normal matrix works fine. See also this answer: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/66691/which-kind-of-diodes-i-should-use-in-buttons-keys-matrix-input-making-gaming-k/66710#66710

Comment: It was late, I was tired, sorry I forgot the "don't" : My intention was to write: "If you don't use a diode separated key matrix, ....".  You're right that you have to press at  least 3 keys to get the ghost effect. And of cause two of the pressed keys must be on the row that is powered "ghostly" by the third pressed key. Mea culpa, thinking while writing is helpful. ;-) By the way, I have already created some keyboards, it's not my main business but from time to time ... . They have to work in harsh environments. Sometimes for some reasons I'm not allowed to place diodes in the key matrix.

Comment: One of these projects required me to allow the user to press a maximum of four keys out of sixty four and I was not allowed to use diodes. In the end we solved it by using a 16 Bit shift register. We powered the rows and read the cols and we had to handle the ghost keys. We used an algorithm that was called the anti ghosting algorithm in the literature we studied. This checks whether the signals of the pressed keys comes quick enough to interpret it as a ghost signal or if the user had really pressed the keys.

Comment: We did not check how quick the user released the key we check for the very fast time the power jumps from one row to the "ghost" row. The smaller the checked  time intervals, the more reliable is the recognition of a keys. And that you dream of testing in the nano second scale. But even with this algorithm the reading was not reliable because sometimes we were not fast enough or the the keys were pressed in an an unlucky order. We detect user pressed keys as ghost keys. Then we tried to build a Resistor based DAC. with 7 channels to read the 64 Keys. This works fine but failed in production.

Comment: It failed in production because there was strong EMI. And the analog inputs got unreliable. At the end we capitulated and used four of the sixteen bit shift registers to read each key separately. The was the long story of the short comment above. I didn't what to teach you how keyboards work. I just want to show you what we had done, so could used it for your decisions . I'm not a native English speaker. In fact my English is very poor. So I did not recognize, that I made some errors, and I had not written with the precision I would write if I write German texts. But I promise, I'll  practice

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer Yes, "don't" can make big difference sometimes :) My English is also far from perfect (4. language learned) - and I am from Czech. Your answer confused me, so I went to longer explanation. At the end there is none disagreement between us :)

Comment: Yes, that's right ! And I forgot: Thank you for pointing me to the errors. ........ And there is still one thing. You wrote, you want to connect the keyboard using USB (among other methods). If you intent to use the keyboard as a HID device (which you should ;-) ), the board you'll choose should be able for this. I know that the Leonardo and the DUE have this feature. Here is a link that explain the usage for a keyboard: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/keyboard/

Comment: And if you choose for a e.g. Mega as suggested in one answer, this video might be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTlM27jzOIQ

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer I am using Micro so far, which have also HW USB ability :) http://micro-corner.gilhad.cz/blog/Arduino/progs/KlikiMouse3/images/klikimouse.s.jpg http://micro-corner.gilhad.cz/blog/Arduino/progs/KlikiMouse3/2019-04-29-Arduino-progs-Klikimouse3.html as it is pretty cheap from Aliexpress :)

Comment: Funny, I saw this part so often in the internet stores but was not aware of that feature. It has a 32u4 MCU. Thank you for pointing me to it. So you will use this in addition to a bigger MCU that can read the keyboard inputs? Or do you plan to use shift registers (aka port expander; like the MCP23S17)?

Comment: If you are interested in other brands: Do you know the STM32 Nucleo F-series?  These are boards with STM32 ARM M0-M4 MCUs in a price range from 10 to 20 dollars with arduino headers and own headers (Morpho) with a full pin out ~ 55 IO Pins. They have also a rich set of communication interfaces. Here is a link to the F3 series MCU https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f3-series.html. (Oh and they have a flexible interconnect matrix. Choose your pins ;-) )

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer I would probably use much cheaper 74HC138 or 74HC595 for output or 74HC165 for inputs :) or just use Blue Pill as I did for old PS/2 keyboard :) http://download.gilhad.cz/STM-keyboard.s.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with a Mega2560. Up to 86 IO if you use a board that breaks out all IO pins, otherwise 70 on the Arduino version. With a little attention to the physical chip pin mapping to the board you can have several full 8-bit ports while also using SPI, I2C, and Serial via one of 4 UARTs. I'd recommend keeping Tx(0)/Rx(0) free for comm's with PC via USB adapter for code download/debug. Tx1/Rx1, Tx2/Rx2, Tx3/Rx3 are them free for 0/5V level comm's, or other levels via USB adapter, RS232 adapter, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The expander MCP23S17 (spi), with a CS, is a good extention (16 I/O configurable)
That should do it !